# Fact Tables - CRM - Customer X Events

Tags: crm, data-warehouse, fact

I am new in DW and I have a simple question. Imagine that I want to create a DW to analytical CRM.

I have a fact table called Event and I have a dimension called Customer.

The problem is. One event can have N Customers, and one Customer can be in N events.

So the relation between Customer(dimension) and Events(fact) are NxN. Is that schema is correct? If not, what schema will be better for this case?

Comment: Is Event both fact & dimension?  You presumably have a table between Customer and Event if there's a many-many mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In essence a fact table is a many-to many table in between dimensions. So in your case,

- `Event` table is a dimension table.

**OR**

- There is another fact table `Event Participation` which shares some dimensions with the `Event` or has the `EventSequenceNumber` as a degenerate dimension.